# How to create a neighbours map from a given nodes list in Scala?

Tags: scala, graph

Suppose I have `List[Node]` -- a list of nodes and a function `isConnected(n1:Node, n2:Node):Boolean`. Now I would like to create a map `Map[Node, List[Node]]`, which maps every node to the list of its neighbours.

I am trying to figure out how to use `groupBy` for that. Does it make sense? How would you create the neighbours map in idiomatic Scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
list.map(node => node -> list.filter(n => isConnected(node, n))).toMap
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming l is your list:

```
l zip (l map (n1 => l filter(n2 => isConnected(n1,n2)))) toMap
```