# Find neighbors of a node

Tags: graph, similarity

How to find neighbors of a node from non-directed graph using scala-programming?
I created graph with node list and edge list, now I need to find neighbor list of each node. Is there any library or any idea how to find neighbor list?

```
val graphx = Graph(nodes,routes)

val label = sc.textFile("label.csv")
val getgdata2 = label.map(line=>line.split(","))
val node11 = getgdata2.map(line=>((line(0)))).distinct   
val verticesWithSuccessors: VertexRDD[Array[VertexId]] = 
graphx.ops.collectNeighborIds(EdgeDirection.Out)
val successorGraph = Graph(verticesWithSuccessors, routes)

val res = successorGraph.vertices.collect()
res.take(5)
--------------------------
Output shows : 
(384,[J@38d17d80)
(454,[J@6ede46f6)
(1084,[J@66273da0)
(1410,[J@2127e66e)
(772,[J@1229a2b7)
Answer should be: 
(384 - 1084, 984,2013)
(454 - 924)
(1084 - 2302,354)
```

I need to see adjacency list for each node. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a neighbours map from a given nodes list in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204491/how-to-create-a-neighbours-map-from-a-given-nodes-list-in-scala)

Comment: No, possible answer should be for node: 384 - 762,982,392